# python: file paths no longer work with imp

Tags: python, filepath, python-import

I recently started using imports to better organize my code in python.  My original code in `file1.py` used the line:

```
def foo():
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    print files
    #do stuff here....
```

Which referenced all the files in the same folder as the code, `print files` showing the correct output as an array of filenames.

However, I recently changed the directory structure to something like this:

```
./main.py
./folder1/file1.py
./folder1/data_file1.csv
./folder1/data_file2.csv
./folder1/......
```

And in main.py, I use:

```
import imp
file1 = imp.load_source('file1', "./folder1/file1.py")
.
.
.

file1.foo()
```

Now, `files` is an empty array. What happened?  I have tried absolute filepaths in addition to relative.  Directly declaring an array with `data_file1.csv` works, but I can't get anything else to work with this import.

What's going on here?

Comment: Are you collecting `file1` and friends into `files`?

Comment: its completely empty? It does not even have `main.py` ?

Comment: @abgordon , are you trying to find files inside `folder1` ?

Comment: `os.path` from `foo()` is used within `main.py` so it recalls `main.py` path and not `file1.py`'s

Comment: @MarkZampedroni this is definitely true but needed the additional `join` code that was suggested below.

Comment: Do you really have a good reason to use `imp.load_source` rather than `import`?

Comment: I had an additional import within the subfolder that was a library of core functions for file1.py, that took the form `core = __import__("coreFunctionsfile1")` and was finding that it didn't really jive the dir/subdir functionality that `imp` provided.  I clearly don't understand this stuff that well so if you like to have a explanation of `imp` vs `__import__` please do so below!

Comment: @abgordon It was just a hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `os.listdir('.')` , you are trying to list the contents of `'.'` (which is the current directory) , but this does not need to be the directory in which the script resides, it would be the directory in which you were in when you ran the script (unless you used `os.chdir()` inside the python script).

You should not depend on the current working directory , instead you can use `__file__` to access the path of the current script, and then you can use [`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) to get the directory in which the script resides.

Then you can use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join the paths of the files you get from `os.listdir()` with the directory of the script and check if those paths are files to create your list of files.

Example -

```
def foo():
    filedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    files = [f for f in (os.path.join(filedir, fil) for fil in os.listdir(filedir)) if os.path.isfile(f)]
    print files
    #do stuff here....
```

Comment: this worked perfectly.  I of course needed an initial check on my 
`for f in files:`
     `if f == 'file1.py':`
         `pass`  
And noticed that I had to change the file check to 

`if f == './folder1/file1.py':`

Which is in line with the suggestion the `'.'`was referencing the folder where main resided.   Thanks!